# Data Rows to String to Array issue

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a very weird problem happening. I have an object populated with a bunch of rows. I can access them all well, but I need to append a "." (dot) to every value inside it, so I end up converting each record  to a string using a for each loop and adding a "." after trimming the values. The issue now however, is that I would like to assign each of these rows (And the rows have only one column/Item) to another array/object, so I can access them later.

The issue is that even when I declare an object/array variable and assign the string converted data rows, the object variable keeps getting converted to a String, and I just cant seem to avoid it.

Please help. Here is a modified code sample:

```
[String] $DBNms = @();

ForEach($DBName in $objDBNms){ 

   $tempText += $DBName.Item(0).ToString().Trim() + "."

   $DBNms += $tempText
}  

 Write-Host($DBNms.GetType()) #And this is showing up a string, while I want it to be an array.
```

And if I print $DBNms, it indeed shows up a string concatenated together into a single string, while I actually want it to be like $DBNms[0] = first Item value, $DBNms[1] = second Item value and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[String] $DBNms = @();` makes `$DBNms` a *type-constrained* variable, due to *type literal* **`[string]`** being placed *to the left* of variable `$DBNms`, whose type is then *locked in* as a string; that is, as **a *single* string**.

**You were looking to create a string *array*, which in PowerShell is represented as `[string[]]`**:

```
[string[]] $DBNames = @()
```

---

PowerShell's type conversions are *automatic* (and very flexible), so that `[String] $DBNms = @()` doesn't report an error, it quietly converts the empty *array* (`@()`) to the empty *string* (as required by the type constraint):

```
PS> [string] $DBNames = @(); '' -eq $DBNames
True
```

---

**A much more efficient way to collect values from multiple iterations in an array is to use the `foreach` statement *as an expression***, which case PowerShell collects the outputs *automatically* for you:

```
[string[]] $DBNms = foreach ($DBName in $objDBNms){ 

   # Output this expression's value as-is.
   # PowerShell will collect the individual iterations' values for you.
   $DBName.Item(0).ToString().Trim() + "."

}
```

The above is not only more concise than your original approach, it is more importantly more efficient:

- In reality you cannot directly *add* (append to) an array, because it is an *immutable* data structure.
- What PowerShell has to do **whenever you use `+=` with an array** is to **allocate a *new* array** behind the scenes, with the original elements copied over and the new element(s) appended; the new array is then automatically assigned back to the variable.

---

Note: The **alternative** and next best solution to using the whole loop as an expression is to use **an *efficiently extensible list type***, notably `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`([`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1)):

```
# Create the list.
# The 'System.' namespace prefix is optional.
[Collections.Generic.List[string]] $DBNms = @()

foreach ($DBName in $objDBNms) { 

   # Add to the list, using its .Add() method.
   # Note: Do NOT try to add with +=
   $DBNms.Add($DBName.Item(0).ToString().Trim() + ".")

}
```

You'll need this approach if your loop does more than outputting a single value per iteration, such as needing to append to *multiple* collections.

Note: It used to be common to use <del>**[`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList)**</del> instances instead; however:

- Use of this type is ***no longer recommended*** (see the warning in the linked help topic); use `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` instead, which additionally allows you to *strongly type* the collection (replace `[object]` with the type of interest, such as `[string]` in the code above).
- It has the drawback of its `.Add()` method having a *return value*, which you need to silence explicitly (e.g., `$null = $lst.Add(...)`), so that it doesn't accidentally pollute your code's output stream (produce unexpected extra output).