# Powershell - extract to csv from the loop

Tags: powershell, foreach

when i tried to extact results from this code

```
$Output = @()
foreach($emailproxy in $emailproxies)
{
if($emailproxy.Mail -like "*com" -or $emailproxy.Mail -like "*org"){ Write-Host $emailproxy.Mail} 
 $Output = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        Mail = $emailproxy.Mail
    } | Select-Object Mail
}

$Output | Export-Csv C:\TempDownloads\results.csv
```

I only get 1 result .. why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each iteration in the loop, you are assigning (overwriting) the value directly to the `$Output` variable, instead of adding the value to the array.

Inside the for loop, you need to replace `$Output =` with `$Output +=`.

- `$Output = <new value>` -> Assign `<new value>` to $Output variable, existing value of `$Output` is overwritten and lost.
- `$Output += <new value>` is equivalent to `$Output = $Output + <new value>`, where `<new value>` and current value of `$Output` are first combined and then assigned to `$Output`.

Comment: Good explanation; @WiktorKostrzewski, while this is the immediate solution to your problem, incrementally "extending" an array in a loop is inefficient, because a _new_ array must be created behind the scenes in every iteration, given that arrays are _immutable_; a much more efficient approach is to use the `foreach` loop as an _expression_ and let PowerShell automatically collect the outputs in an array: `[array] $Output = foreach (...) { ... }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029146/45375).

Comment: To compliment [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) comment, please have a look at: [Why should I avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60708578/1701026)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are overwrighting the variable $output each time. You need to append properties to the psobject using add-member

```
Output = New-Object -TypeName Psobject 
foreach($emailproxy in $emailproxies) { if($emailproxy.Mail -like "*com" -or $emailproxy.Mail -like "*org"){ Write-Host $emailproxy.Mail} 
$Output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Mail" -Value $_.mail
}
 $Output | Export-Csv "filepath"
```

Comment: Add-Member : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:3 char:11
+ $Output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Mail" -Value $_. ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Member], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCommand
 
Add-Member : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.

Comment: The intent is to create an _array_ of custom objects, to be collected in `$Output`.