# PowerShell: Add New Value to Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, scripting, active-directory

Using PowerShell I retrieve information from multiple ActiveDirectory groups and output it to a single CSV file. To each row I want to add the name of the group, in addition to the information retrieved. How can I achieve this?

Desired Result:

```
"CN","Department","co","Company","Group"
"ABCDEF","Media","UK","Global Entertainment","XXX"
```

Current Result:

```
"CN","Department","co","Company"
"ABCDEF","Media","UK","Global Entertainment"
```

My PowerShell code:

```
#Roles to check membership for
$Roles= @(
'XXX' 
'YYY'
)

$FolderName = "C:\"
$OutputAD = @()

foreach ($role in $Roles) {
  $GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $role | select name

  $GroupMembersArray = $GroupMembers | Foreach {"$($_.Name)"}

  $GroupMembersArray | ForEach-Object {
    $UserLookup = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$_'" -Properties CN,Department,co,Company | Select-Object CN,Department,co,Company
    $OutputAD +=  $UserLookup
  } 

}

$OutputAD | Export-Csv "$FolderName\Membership $(get-date -Format yyyy-MMM-dd-HH-mm-ss).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: As an aside: Extending arrays in a loop with `+=` is inefficient, because a _new_ array must be created behind the scenes _in every iteration_, given that arrays are of fixed size; a much more efficient approach is to use a `foreach` loop as an _expression_ and let PowerShell itself collect the outputs in an array: `[array] $outputs = foreach (...) { ... }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375). In case you need to create arrays manually, e.g. to create _multiple_  ones, use an efficiently extensible list type - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029146/45375).

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. In [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) you can add a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties).

Example: `Select-Object CN,Department,co,Company,@{n='Role';e={$role}}`