# Dynamically calculated value for scriptproperty

Tags: powershell, properties, scriptblock, custom-properties, add-member

The script below is a part of a bigger project of converting msgs to pdfs. What I'm having problem with implementing is the `attachments` custom property. I'd like is for it to take custom value based on calculated value based on msg attachments. The `MailItem.Attachments.Count` will not do. It includes images embeden in the body of message. This can be circumvented with the second snippet. I however cannot combide the two.

Main script:

```
$o = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$path = "PATH"
cd $path
gc test.csv|Select -skip 2 -First 1|%{$_|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'BaseName' -Value $_.substring($_.Lastindexof('\')+1).substring(0, $_.substring($_.Lastindexof('\')+1).Lastindexof('.'));
$_|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FileName' -Value $_.substring($_.Lastindexof('\')+1);
$_|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FullName' -Value $_;
$_|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Folder' -Value $_.substring(0, $_.Lastindexof('\'));
$_|Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'New Loc' -Value {if($msg.Attachments.Count -eq 0){$msgDirectory + '\Converted\'}elseif($msg.Attachments.Count -ge 1){$msgDirectory + '\Converted\' + $msgBaseName + '\'}};





$_|Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'Attachments' -Value {IF ((SECOND SNIPPET) -gt 0){"YES"}ELSE{"NO}};




$msgBaseName = $_.BaseName
$msgFullname = $_.FullName
$msgDirectory = $_.Folder
$msgName = $_.Filename

$msg = $o.CreateItemFromTemplate($msgFullname)
}
```

Second part:

```
$results = 0
$msg.Attachments|%{$att = $_
$attach = $att.FileName; 
$file = 'C:\Users\anowak\Downloads\Script_Test\' + $attach
$file
IF(($msg.HTMLBody) -like "*cid:$attach*"){}else{$results ++} #check if 'attachment' present in the body
$results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this will do the trick.

```
$o = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$path = "Path"
cd $path

$output = @()

gc test.csv |
  Select -skip 3 -First 1 | 
  % { 

    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'BaseName' -Value $_.substring($_.Lastindexof('\') + 1).substring(0, $_.substring($_.Lastindexof('\') + 1).Lastindexof('.'))
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FileName' -Value $_.substring($_.Lastindexof('\') + 1)
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FullName' -Value $_
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Folder' -Value $_.substring(0, $_.Lastindexof('\'))
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'New Loc' -Value { if ($msg.Attachments.Count -eq 0) { $msgDirectory + '\Converted\' }elseif ($msg.Attachments.Count -ge 1) { $msgDirectory + '\Converted\' + $msgBaseName + '\' } }

    $msgBaseName = $_.BaseName
    $msgFullname = $_.FullName
    $msgDirectory = $_.Folder
    $msgName = $_.Filename

    $msg = $o.CreateItemFromTemplate($msgFullname)

    $results = 0
    $msg.Attachments | 
      % { 
        $att = $_
        $attach = $att.FileName
        $file = 'Path' + $attach
        IF (($msg.HTMLBody) -like "*cid:$attach*") {} else { $results++ } #check if 'attachment' present in the body
        $results
      }
  
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'Attachments' -Value { if ($results -eq 0) { 'NO' } else { 'Yes' } };

    $output += $_ | Select FullName, FileName, "New Loc", Attachments

  }

$output | Out-GridView
```

To explain what I've done. I placed 'second part' before `Add-Member` along with `COM Object` so that calculations can be made. I've tested it and works. The only issue is that I have to restart ISE everytime. Otherwise the `$results` variable will remain populated and the script will not work as intended.

Comment: As an aside: Extending arrays in a loop with `+=` is inefficient, because a _new_ array must be created behind the scenes _in every iteration_, given that arrays are of fixed size; a much more efficient approach is to let PowerShell itself collect the outputs in an array: `[array] $outputs = gc test.csv ...` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375). In case you need to create arrays manually, e.g. to create _multiple_  ones, use an efficiently extensible list type - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029146/45375).

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: It's great that you're sharing a solution, but the formatting of your code makes it difficult to understand what's going on. Consider using proper indentation and inserting empty lines to improve the structure.

Comment: Those are good arguments, but... I cannot use enything above  5.1.19041.1682. Company device - no admin rights to update. Same thing fo VS. I will see the post you mentioned though. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. It is possible to install Visual Studio Code without admin rights.

Comment: Not in this case. Any installation has to be run via admin account. It would have to be a portable version.

Comment: @mklement0 believe me I tried, but it comes out even more garbled. Any pointers?

Comment: I see - so there's some sort of watchdog software that intercepts attempts to run user-level installers? As for the ISE problem: of course, you can initialize `$results` at the start of your script to prevent lingering values, but it's hard to do that consistently, for all variables that may be affected. As for formatting: I gave it a shot - see if it works for you.

Comment: @mklement0 I belive that it's the domain user settings that prevent instalation, but I'm no expert in this regard. As for using `[system.colletions.arraylist]`, I measured the script with the original `+=` solution and `arraylist` object. The difference of 7 miliseconds may seem insignificant  for small number of files (there are 6 in test group) but it would pile up. Thanks. Your formating made my code look more readable. Thanks again.