# PowerShell replace

Tags: powershell, replace, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm using PowerShell to run and export a SQL query. By default my output file has " " around the values, but one of the requirements is to only return raw data, so I piped in `| % {$_ -replace '"',""} |`
to address that, however one of the fields is a text field that contains measurements that have " for length I need to maintain.

My questions is how to apply `| % {$_ -replace '"',""} |` to everything BUT one field.

Comment: Without current and desired sample data it is more challenging to help you.

Comment: I still want to remove the double quoting surrounding the results, for ALL fields, but want to retain the double quoting if it is part of the data results.

"MOD70103- 24" X 16"  PP2 54W" X 40D" CLR Black" should return MOD70103- 24" X 16"  PP2 54W" X 40D" CLR Black

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- In  [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) the [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv) and [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Csv) cmdlets now have `-UseQuotes` and `-QuoteFields` parameters, which would allow you to create your CSV data without double-quoted fields to begin with; e.g.:

  ```bash
  ... | Export-Csv out.csv -UseQuotes Never
  ```
- In *Windows PowerShell* these cmdlets *invariably* output double-quoted fields, necessitating manual post-processing, as shown below.

---

Try the following:

```bash
... | % { $_ -replace '(?<=^|",)"|"(?=,"|$)' -replace '""', '"' }
```

Note:

- The **assumption is that fields with embedded `"` values *do not also contain `,`***, because the removal of the enclosing double quotes would then break the partitioning of the line into fields.
- The extra `-replace` operation,  `-replace '""', '"'` unescapes the field-embedded `"` chars.

  - Note that a well-formed CSV requires `"` chars. inside double-quoted fields to be escaped as `""`.
    `Export-Csv` / `ConvertTo-Csv` do perform this escaping.
  - However, `Import-Csv` / `ConvertFrom-Csv` also tolerate input *without* this kind of escaping.
  - Either way, the above command works: if the embedded `"` chars. *aren't* escaped as `""`, `-replace '""', '"'` is simply a *no-op*.

A simple, self-contained example:

```bash
@'
"foo","bar"
"baz","qu""ux"
'@ -split '\r?\n' | 
  % { $_ -replace '(?<=^|",)"|"(?=,"|$)' -replace '""', '"' }
```

Output (only the field internal `"` was retained):

```bash
foo,bar
baz,qu"ux
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/f5JCya/1) - note that, because the linked page uses *C#* string-literal syntax, the `"` chars. in the regex are doubled.

---

Note that you can speed up processing considerably if you load your entire CSV file *as a whole* into memory and modify your regex with the `Multiline` regex option (`(?m)`), which then causes `^` and `$` to match the start and end of *each line*:

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw your.csv) -replace '(?m)(?<=^|",)"|"(?=,"|$)' -replace '""', '"'
```

Answer (score -1):

If I had a string content as similar to a CSV file content with 3 columns: Col1, Col2, Col3 I would write something like this:

```
$csvSimilarContent = @"
Col1,Col2,Col3
"AAA","MOD70103- 24`" X 16`" PP2 54W`" X 40D`" CLR Black","CCC"
"@

# takes a string that contains CSV data as input and creates a 
# custom object for each row in the CSV data. 
$content = $csvSimilarContent | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Create an empty array for CSV content
$modifiedContent = @()

# Iterate through each row in the CSV file
foreach ($row in $content) {
    # Remove surrounding double quotes in fields
    $row.Col1 = $row.Col1 -replace '^"|"$', ''
    $row.Col2 = $row.Col2 -replace '^"|"$', ''
    $row.Col3 = $row.Col3 -replace '^"|"$', ''

    # Add the modified row to the modified content array
    $modifiedContent += $row
}

# Display the modified content
$modifiedContent
```

The script removes only double quotes, that surround the fields.

Note: Extending arrays in a loop with += is inefficient

Comment: Note that the double quotes with _syntactic_ function, i.e.. those _enclosing_ field values are _removed_ when you use `Import-Csv` to parse a CSV file; that is, the property values of the resulting objects do _not_ contain these double quotes, so there is no point in trying to replace them.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, the intent is to remove the field-enclosing double quotes _from the text in the file_. In Windows PowerShell,
`Export-Csv` invariably produces CSV files with fields enclosed in double quotes. While that _shouldn't_ be a problem for compliant CSV parsers
(and it isn't for `Import-Csv`), situationally a file's consumer may choke on them.

Comment: As an aside: Extending arrays in a loop with `+=` is inefficient, because a _new_ array must be created behind the scenes _in every iteration_, given that arrays are of fixed size; a much more efficient approach is to use a `foreach` loop as an _expression_ and let PowerShell itself collect the outputs in an array: `[array] $outputs = foreach (...) { ... }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375). In case you need to create arrays manually, e.g. to create _multiple_  ones, use an efficiently extensible list type - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029146/45375).

Comment: Yes - of course - enclosing field values are removed when you using Import-Csv to parse a CSV file.

Comment: So why are you trying to remove double quotes that are no longer there?

Comment: In your updated answer the `-replace` statements still aren't doing anything.

Comment: Also, instead of saying "this is inefficient", I suggest avoiding the ill-advised practice to begin with.