# Using variable in Select-Object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, html-table, invoke-command, scriptblock, select-object

I have a table which is created using Time as the Column names.  However if the first row does not have data in certain Hours(column) then the column does not show the column for the rest of the table.  Thus, I'm trying to create a dynamic select statement which will get every hour since midnight and use these hours as search variables.  I have accomplish to get the Select statement created but its not invoking/executing the query.

Any suggestion to get data returned and build the HTML table would be great appreciated.

Code:

```
$UniversalCurrTime = ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('h tt')
$UniversalMidnight = ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().Date).ToString('h tt')
$hoursBetween = $UniversalMidnight

Write-host 'This is midnight: ' $UniversalMidnight
Write-host 'This is Current time: ' $UniversalTime
$HourSpan = @()
$HourSpan += 'VaultName'
$HourSpan += $UniversalMidnight #($hoursBetween).ToString('h tt')
Do{
    $HourSpan += "'" + ($hoursBetween).ToString('h tt') + "'"
    $hoursBetween = (Get-date $hoursBetween).AddHours(1)
    Write-host 'This is time being added to collection: ' $hoursBetween
}while($hoursBetween -le $UniversalCurrTime)

$HourSpan += 'TotalMessages'

$selectObject = '$reportList |Select-Object ' + (($HourSpan -split '\n') -join ",") + '| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue'
$html = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$selectObject}
```

Output on the screen but not executed to return data.

`$reportList |Select VaultName,'12 AM','1 AM','2 AM','3 AM','4 AM','5 AM','6 AM','7 AM','8 AM', '9 AM','10 AM','11 AM','12 PM','1 PM','2 PM','3 PM','4 PM','5 PM','6 PM','7 PM', '8 PM', '9PM', '10 PM', '11 PM', 'TotalMessages' |Where-Object { -Not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

This statement should be executed.

Comment: Why are you using To String?  Your comparison expect the two dates to be DateTime, but your code is trying to compare two strings : $hoursBetween -le $UniversalCurrTime

Comment: I convert it to string to get the hour (e.g. 1PM, 2PM....)  to add it to the collection, then just below its reverted to DateTime before the comparison,

Comment: What would be in the $reportList variable?

Comment: $reportsList contains the name of the product -VaultName-  and count of messages added per hour to the Database table and the sum of they count -TotalMessages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$selectObject = '$reportList |Select-Object ' + (($HourSpan -split '\n') -join ",") + '| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue'`

The above creates a *string* value.

> `$html = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$selectObject}`

The above - which could be simplified to `$html = & { $selectObject }` and ultimately `$html = $selectObject` - *outputs the string stored in `$selectObject`*, which explains what you saw.

---

Leaving aside whether the array stored in `$HourSpan` is (a) constructed efficiently,<sup>[1]</sup> (b) whether the intended chronological comparisons work and (c) assuming that `$HourSpan += 'VaultName'` and `$HourSpan += 'TotalMessages'` are *removed*, you're probably looking for the following:

```bash
$html = 
  $reportList |
  Select-Object (@('VaultName') + $HourSpan + 'TotalMessages') |
  ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

That is, **you can pass a dynamically constructed array of property names *directly* to the (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter of [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)**.

With an array as the LHS - which use of `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) ensures - the `+` operator performs (flat) *array concatenation*.

---

**PowerShell rarely requires constructing commands dynamically *as strings* and *doing so should generally be avoided***, due to  inherent *security risks*, but in cases where this is necessary, you have two options:

- For *one-off* calls *in the caller's scope*, use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression); e.g.:

  ```bash
  $commandString = 'Get-Date'
  Invoke-Expression $commandString
  ```
- For *repeatable* calls, construct a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) from the string, using [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create), which you can invoke repeatedly on demand, either via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) - in a *child scope* - or via `.` , the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) - directly in the *caller's* scope:

  ```bash
  $commandString = 'Get-Date'
  $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($commandString)
  # Invoke the script block on demand, in a child scope.
  # To invoke it directly in the caller's scope, use:
  #  . $scriptBlock
  & $scriptBlock
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Extending arrays in a loop with `+=` is inefficient, because a *new* array must be created behind the scenes *in every iteration*, given that arrays are of fixed size; a much more efficient approach is to use a statement such as a `do { ... } while (...)` or `foreach` loop as an *expression* and let PowerShell itself collect the outputs in an array: `[array] $outputs = foreach (...) { ... }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375). In case you need to create arrays manually, e.g. to create *multiple*  ones, use an efficiently extensible list type - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029146/45375).</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!   I removed $HourSpan += 'VaultName' and $HourSpan += 'TotalMessages'  modified my script with your recommended solution and with worked!  Thank you.  $html = 
  $reportList |
  Select-Object (@('VaultName') + $HourSpan + 'TotalMessages') |
  ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  You offer a load of knowledge in you submission thus I will take my time to digest of statement contained therein.

Comment: I know you did not delve much in the the $HourSpan logic much but for future readers I had to make a slight change from $HourSpan += "'" + ($hoursBetween).ToString('h tt') + "'" to  $HourSpan += $(DateTime $hoursBetween).ToString('h tt').  I'm currently reading your other suggested post on how to make the addition to the Array more efficient.